# i'm not able to do Publisher/Subscriber in rabbitmq in ubuntu22.04, i'm not finding anything about it

Tags: rabbitmq, ubuntu-22.04

i'm not able to do Publisher/Subscriber in rabbitmq in ubuntu22.04, i'm not finding anything about it. I use docker for this, I can create the management with port 8080:15672, I cannot use 5672. And when I send some code to Publisher/Subscriber nothing appears in the management, (obs: I used http//localhost:8080 to access rabbitmq management)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you open traffic redirection to port `5672`? For eg. If you are using docker run, then `-p 5672:5672`